# Xbox 360 region protection - system link between PAL and NTSC

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock, halo-3, xbox-system-link

I live in a country where we have a mix of regions here since all consoles are independently imported.

So I have an NTSC Xbox which I bought in the US some years ago. Me and my friends are going to have this sweet LAN party this weekend and I'm wondering if another Xbox, a PAL one, will work with my NTSC Xbox using System Link (connecting them with a LAN cable)? It's an effort for me to get that extra console so I'm trying to figure things out up ahead.

We'll probably just play Halo 3 or Reach which to my understanding are not the kind of games that are region-locked. All consoles mentioned are not 'modded', all legal and up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I can now confirm: A new slim, PAL Xbox 360 worked with a relatively old NTSC (60gb/hdmi) Xbox 360. System Link was flawless, we connected the two directly with a lan cable

*HOWEVER: The two copies of Halo 3 we had were both NTSC, not PAL. I am not sure whether this would work with PAL+NTSC game copies. p.s Halo 3 > Reach*

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give this an attempt, although I cannot test it.

While searching on the web, most people say the Xbox isn't the factor, but rather the game is. Some are region-locked, and some are region-free.

It appears Halo: Reach is region-free. [Taken from Here](http://www.bungie.net/News/content.aspx?type=topnews&link=BWU_082710) (more than half way down the page in the Questions section)

> Q. Will Halo: Reach be region-free?
>
> A. According to Domenic, Halo: Reach is “world signed,” meaning you
>   can play any regional copy in any region on any retail Xbox 360.

I could not find a specific answer for Halo 3, but I think you will be able to play Halo: Reach with your friends during this LAN party.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Good source. I noticed that most games that are directly Microsoft's (Bungie was Microsoft's 2000-2007) are region-free. According to this list Halo 3 is region-free as well: http://forum.xbox-sky.cc/xbox360_regional_compatibility_guide/
I still couldn't find an accurate answer to my more-complex question though. It would make sense that the console hardware and the way they connect isn't affected by region protection, but I just have a feeling it might be a thing that was restricted intentionally